# Mechanism for If-statements with str in python

Tags: python

Can I be sure that `''` always will be considered `False` while anything else isn't?

```
>>> if '':
...    print('bah')
...
>>> if 'x':
...    print('bah')
...
bah
```

Why or why not? **What mechanism in Python defines this behavior?**

If `''` is evaluated as `False`, why do I get this result:

```
>>> if '' == False:
...    print('bah')
...
>>>
```

Comment: yes - {}, [], (), None, False, 0 and '' (empty string) are resolved as False

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:

- `None`
- `False`
- zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
- any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
- any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value `False`.

All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

Comment: But neither `'' is False` or `'' == False` is True? :)

Comment: That's because if statement implicitly converts given expression result to bool type. So bool('') is False and bool('') == False is what actually tested.

Comment: @Qiau: `bool('') is False`, and `bool('') == False` are True.

Comment: But if `'' is False` is evaluated as `bool('') is False`, how come the first one results in `False` and the other `True` ?

Comment: @Qiau Think of it like this: `bool('')` returns False, therefore `bool('') == False` would return True

Comment: @Qiau:  What gives you the impression `'' is False` is evaluated as `bool('') is False`?  It's not, as evidenced by the different results.  Values are implicitly converted to `bool` only if they are used in a place where only a boolean value makes sense, such as the condition after `if` or `while`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: from Rostyslav's comment, but I also realize it isn't the truth since evidence tells me different. But if I type `if '' == False:`, shouldn't that be a typical place where `''` is converted to bool?

Comment: remember 'is' is not the same comparison as '=='.  'is' compares identities.  So `'' is False` is comparing the identity of '' with the identity of False which will clearly not be the same.

Comment: @Qiau: No, it shouldn't.  If any value occurring in an expression after `if` would be converted to `bool`, we would end up with `if 2 == 3` being interpreted as `if bool(2) == bool(3)`.  Only the result of the expression after `if` is converted to `bool`, but the rules of how the exxpression is evaluated are the same as in any other context.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Makes sense. So, why do I get different results from `if '':` and `if '' == False:`?

Comment: @Qiau: You don't get different results.  The first expression is the empty string, which is considered `False` in a Boolean context.  The second expression compares `''` and `False`.  They are not equal, so the result is `False` again.

Comment: @Qiau: The implicit conversion to `bool` is applied to the entire expression. `if '':` is the same as `if bool('')`. `if ''==False` is the same as `if bool(''==False)`.

Comment: @Qiau: you never want to use `==` or `is` to compare with `True` or `False`. Use `if not '':` to express what you're asking.